# Triple equal in JavaScript compare the value of type first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, triple-equals

Triple equal measure the value as well as type. But I want to know the order like it first compares the value and returns on false or vice versa.

Comment: Why exactly do you think it matters?

Comment: The type is checked first.  Here's "The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm" from the JavaScript (ECMAScript) spec: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked duplicate links to the official standard, if you're interested in the nitty gritty: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6

Answer (score 1):

It checks the type first:

https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6

```
If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
If Type(x) is Null, return true.
If Type(x) is Number, then
    If x is NaN, return false.
    If y is NaN, return false.
    If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
    If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
    If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
    Return false.
If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
```